# Is there a way to select/set a theme through the VS Code extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to be able to set/select a theme at a given time through the extension API.

Example:
`6:00 PM — Set theme "OneDark Pro"`

So far, I've been reading the extension API docs and have not found information that could help me in this manner.

This would be my first extension & Typescript project, so I'm sure I might be missing an obvious point.

```
vscode.ThemeColor.set('themeName');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `"workbench.colorTheme"` setting (note that it's only available for workspace-local `settings.json` files). Additionally, there's an [API to read and modify settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration). This means you can do something like this:

```
var folders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
if (folders !== undefined) {
  vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('workbench', folders[0].uri)
      .update(
          'colorTheme', 'themeName', vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Workspace);
}
```

Note: this logic is simplified and assumes that the workspace only consists of a single folder / won't work for [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).